# Is it possible to simulate keystrokes in a shell script without installing packages like xdotool?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, simulate, keystroke

I'd like to simulate keystroke using a shell script, in order to trigger shortcuts for example.

Is it possible to do that without installing packages like xdotool?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Thanks!

Comment: Define "native commands" here? `xdotool` is certainly "native" code. Do you mean "preinstalled"? If so preinstalled in what sense?

Comment: Hum yeah, sorry. I meant preinstalled indeed.

Comment: Preinstalled where? Under what circumstances? For what distribution? For what versions of that distribution? Under what spin?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: A lot of shortcut functionality can be triggered more safely and robustly through commands, but it depends entirely on the program and shortcut.

Comment: I wouldn't say "a lot" but certainly some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Input events can only be triggered via software by using either uinput or XTest, neither of which have "native" commands.